# C++ Preventing Int Overflow for addition?

Tags: c++, integer, overflow

In my C++ code I have:

```
int c=(a+b)/2;
```

I know for sure that the final result won't cause integer overflow but this isn't guaranteed for (a+b)

Here is my error message:

> Line 20: Char 27: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1063376696 + 2126753390 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:31:27

How can I solve this type of problem?

Comment: Presumably you mean integer overflow, not stack overflow. If a and b are integers and can be larger than 2^31 when summed, then you need a larger data type like int64

Comment: Line 20: Char 27: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1063376696 + 2126753390 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:31:27

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow didn't help, see my error message

Comment: @daniel *"see my error message"* - you mean the one on your screen that we *can't* see? We're not mind readers. Error messages belong in your question. Regardless, `int c = a + (b-a)/2;`, under the premise that `b >= a` holds water, will prevent the additive overflow of `a+b`.

Comment: @WhozCraig amazing!

Comment: @daniel No. *math*. Btw. the same problem still exists, but now only when `a < 0` and `b > 0` for sufficiently small and large `a` and `b`. So take that caveat for what its worth. If your `a` and `b` are always `> 0` and ordered it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the operation with 64 bit ints and then cast back to 32 bits.

```
int c = int((std::int64_t(a) + std::int64_t(b)) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a standard library function which avoids overflow:

   ```
   std::midpoint(a, b);
   ```
2. Cast to a larger type which can avoid overflow:

   ```
   static_cast<int>((static_cast<std::int64_t>(a) + static_cast<std::int64_t>(b))/2);
   ```
3. Detect it with compiler-specific flags, e.g. `-ftrapv`, or built-ins, e.g. `__builtin_add_overflow`:

   ```
   if (__builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &result))
       throw std::out_of_range("overflow");
   ```
4. Perform the calculation in such a way as to avoid overflow (break it into cases and figure out what it takes to avoid overflow in each case):

   ```
   using U = unsigned int;
   return a>b ? a-(static_cast<U>(a)-b)/2 : a+(static_cast<U>(b)-a)/2;
   ```

https://godbolt.org/z/T3rPdq

Answer (score 1):

Just use int c=a+(b-a)/2; if both a and b are positive. Otherwise you can use above mentioned approaches

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think the answer might be improved. Wİth explanation, formating etc. But still thanks for the useful answer.